# In the Lydian Chromatic Concept, how are the horizontal scales formed?

Tags: theory, scales, lydian-chromatic-concept

In George Russell's *The Lydian Chromatic Concept of Tonal Organization*, he introduces the notion of "horizontal scales":

> They are horizontal because they include the fourth degree in their structure (B♭ in the F Lydian Chromatic Scale). (p. 17)

This is in contrast to vertical scales, which include the Lydian B♮.

But my question is how he derives the four horizontal scales, which are:

1. F major: F G A B♭ C D E
2. F major flat seventh: F G A B♭ C D E♭
3. F major augmented fifth: F G A B♭ C♮ C♯ D E
4. F Lydian flat seventh: F (G) A♭ A♮ B♭ B♮ C D E♭ (E)

As far as I can tell, there is no explanation for how these scales are formed, which seems really odd for someone basing his entire theory on the acoustical properties of the harmonic series.

How are these scales formed? Frankly, it almost seems as if (especially in the final scale) he just threw some darts at a board until he decided he was done creating his scale.

Comment: I’m glad you’re asking because I’ve also had questions about that book. I wonder if there’s at least some amount of learning to improvise by ear over common jazz chord progressions is part of where the scales are from, at least from the authors perspective.

Comment: Without being familiar with this concept as a whole the best I can figure is horizontal scales contain a P4 instead of a #4. As for that final scale, i saw a source that calls it the “African American Blues Scale”. It’s not as random as it appears, it is basically what is commonly referred to as the blues scale, a minor pentatonic with a #4/b5 chromatic passing tone with a major pentatonic scale superimposed over it. Without knowing this was in his book I have always felt like this actually is the complete blues scale because it contains the elements of both major and minor tonalities.

Comment: …although the E natural is not included in my description it allows double chromatic approaches to the tonic amd is also the leading tone. BTW, why are there parentheses on the G and E?

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy He also calls this the "African-American Blues Scale," but I don't believe he explains the parentheses. But even though this scale has a name, my question is ultimately: why this scale? Why not any other scales that have that perfect fourth scale degree?

Comment: Actually I saw that name in an online “Cliff Note” explanation of his concept. I haven’t read the book although I probably unknowingly apply some of its concepts to my playing from other things I’ve learned. This is the article I read: https://www.thejazzpianosite.com/jazz-piano-lessons/modern-jazz-theory/lydian-chromatic-concept/ There is no explanation on how he arrived at these scales, only that there is a hierarchy for using them from consonance to dissonance over a given chord.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy - yes, that last one is an amalgamation of major blues and minor blues scales, (include G), but the E escapes me. It could almost do with Gb, so the tonic could be approached chromatically from either direction - commonplace in jazz.

Comment: @Tim I believe no note in the chromatic scale is completely useless in blues. The thing is to be selective about WHICH notes you use. Using them all at once will sound like you’re practicing scales as I’m sure you know.. I might start on the major pentatonic, switch to the tonic minor pentatonic on the IV chord, etc.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy - I lost count of the number of students I told 'there's a scale (whatever one they're learning), and those notes will work *best* in those cicumstances - but - all 12 are up for grabs in any key. All are quite usable - go away and find where the 'odd' ones come out to play.' And that's without considering the 'quarter-notes' we use in the blues. Maybe not so much on bass, though? Yes, my path through for students was often maj. pent,> min. pent.>maj.blues,>min blues, one verse each, gradually getting 'grittier' for want of a better word.

Comment: Horizontal scales are formed by turning the score sideways.

Comment: @Tim Minor comment, in the U.S. (not sure where you're from) we use the term 'quarter tones' to refer to microtones that are one half of a half-step.

Comment: @user3235 - stone me, I used another anagram of the correct word !! Blues uses just about any fraction of a tone - 3/4 gets used a lot too. Profile says England. Yes, microtones have been discovered there too...

Answer (score 1):

As explained by him. Vertical gravity has to do with the gravitational pull of harmony (within chords) while the horizontal gravity has to do with the gravitational pull of melody. Here he is talking about it:

Comment: Can you explain the gravitational pull concept a bit? What is pulled by what to where? In what circumstances can this pull be observed, how? What kind of an experiment can I do to notice the existence of this alleged phenomenon? Physical gravity is quite easily demonstrated in practice.

Comment: I don't know to be honest... Found the video and thought to share

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica  In theory, the even intervals, 2nds, 4ths and to a lesser degree 6ths, are unstable and typically resolved downward. 
This is most likely what he is calling 'gravity'.
This is true for pure major an minor scales, but if those degrees are sharpened, they will normally act as upward leading tones.  There are exceptions to that, as an augmented 4th is resolved downward fairly frequently.

Comment: @user3235 Ok thanks, that seems to make some sense. Though I don't particularly like the way these "resolving tendencies" are explained as if they were some kind of laws of nature, when it all depends on this one culture and practice where movements like that are done so often that composers, players, listeners take them for granted. There are other cultures and conventions and practices.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica  I'm not sure what to tell you. I grew up in the U.S. and studied Western music theory, the same as Russell, and that has been the prevailing theory in Western music for the last 700 years or so.  Also, please keep in mind that only Western music dealt with polyphony, so there were no other music theories that needed to address the concept of dissonance.

Comment: @user3235 I mean, instead of saying that a note "is a tension" and "has a tendency", say that _composers_ and _players_ in certain circles have a tendency of thinking of that note as a tension and the _people_ have a tendency to "resolve" it. In blues, you have dominant sevenths all over and you don't think of that as a tension that has to be resolved. If you "resolve" the dominant seventh in blues chords, you break the whole thing. It's about what people are used to doing and expecting. What else could there be than what there is - your own mind and cultural fixations are the limiting factor.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica  It is not isolated notes that are in tension, but intervals. 
I agree that minor seventh intervals and dominant sevenths are considered dissonant per classical harmony.  However, non-altered chords have relatively low dissonance and today unaltered 7ths, 9ths, 11ths and 13ths are considered acceptable without resolution. But I don't think anyone would consider a chord with 2 stacked minor 9ths as acceptable. So, yes, exposure makes a difference, but there are auditory effects that can't be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

1. The first scale is just the standard F major scale:

   F G A B♭ C D E F

The reason the standard F major scale is used over the lydian mode for horizontal playing is that the B♮, unless resolved upwards, can sound out of place against other chords in the key.

2. Russell's F major flat seventh 'scale' is the mixolydian mode relative to Bb.
   In the key of B♭, the seventh degree is F. The seventh chord built off of F in Bb consists of F A C Eb, and so the most consonant scale choice will use E♭ instead of E♮.

   B♭ C D Eb **F G A B♭ C D E♭ F** G A B♭
3. The F major augmented fifth scale is a bit peculiar for a couple of reasons.

   F G A B♭ C♮ C♯ D E

Clearly, the C♯ is is going to fit better with chords with a raised 5th.

Something that is obvious but should be stated is that a scale or mode to be played over a chord or sequence of chords depends upon the specific chords and how dissonant your soloing is intended to be.

The first peculiarity for me is that while plain augmented triads, and less rarely, augmented major seventh chords are used in jazz, the most common variety of chords with augmented 5ths found are dominant (flatted) sevenths.
The second peculiarity is that Russell has a chromatic progression in the scale between the C♮ and D♮. I assume that he intended this scale to sound 'bluesy'.

Since most augmented chords are also dominant 7ths, and that contiguous chromatic notes tend to "stick out", a more practical scale for dominants with raised 5ths might be the ascending melodic minor beginning from the 4th degree.
This contains the root, major 3rd, augmented 5th and flatted 7th, without any contiguous successions of minor 2nds.

C D Eb **F G A B C D E♭ F** G A B C

Another alternative to the F major augmented fifth scale is a whole tone scale starting from F.

4. The lydian flat seventh scale.

   F (G) Ab A Bb B C D Eb (E)

As others have correctly pointed out, Russell is just listing the most commonly used tones played to create a 'blues' sound.